# Preposition with 'common': 'to', 'with' or 'between'?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

Say, an element 'a' occurs in two sets: X={'a','b'} and Y= {'a','c'}.

So, what preposition should be used in the blank of the following sentence:

'a' is common element ___ sets X and Y.

It's 'to', 'with' or 'between' ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use all three, but your sentence should read

> 'a' is **a** common element ___ sets X and Y.
>
> 'a' is a common element **to** sets X and Y.
>   'a' is a common element **with** sets X and Y.
>   'a' is a common element **between** sets X and Y.

Comment: How woild you explain the use of 'to'?

Comment: " 'a' is common to *(both)* sets X and Y."

Comment: I see. We can omit 'both' right?

Comment: Yes, "both" may be omitted, but personally I would say " 'a' is common to both X and Y" since it's probably already known that X and Y are sets and belonging to "both" is what is emphasized.

Answer (score -1):

You can use between in this sentence 'a' is common element ___ sets X and Y.
Between is used when naming distinct, individual items so it shows clear meaning.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.